# Checking if a child has at least 3 parents in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I attempted to solve a problem where you are given a list of facts like:

```
parent(a,b).
```

where `b` is the parent of `a`,
and I needed to write a clause that determines if someone has at least 3 parents.

Here's my attempt

```
has3Parent(A) :- parent(A,B), parent(A,C), parent(A,D).
```

With my attempt,

if `A` has 1 parent, it will return true once,

if `A` has 2 parents, it will return true 8 times,

and if `A` has 3 parents, it will return true 27 times.

I'm rather new to Prolog and I cannot wrap my head around as to why this could be, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you never assured that `B`, `C` and `D` were different people, you will always get `true` as long as `A` has even a single `parent`.

So the situation with 1 `parent` is simple; with 2, you have these eight combinations:

```
A = jane, B = jane, C = jane
A = jane, B = jane, C = john
A = jane, B = john, C = jane
A = jane, B = john, C = john
A = john, B = jane, C = jane
A = john, B = jane, C = john
A = john, B = john, C = jane
A = john, B = john, C = john
```

Even if you just say they're not equal, you'll get false for less than 3 and true for 3 or more; but you'll still be getting multiple solutions, because order will matter.

Ideally you'd use `findall/3` to get the set of parents and count it, which will give you a singular solution. Something like:

```
has3Parent(A) :- findall(P, parent(A, P), Ps), length(Ps, 3).
```

(Also note that unlike the previous, this tests whether `A` has *exactly* 3 parents, not *at least* 3 parents. In order to get the previous idea to test for exactly 3 parents, you would have to say that besides `B`, `C` and `D` being different, there also does not exist `E` different from all of them that is also a `parent`. The `findall` solution though is easy to adapt for different kinds of comparison, since you are dealing with a number, not a bunch of unruly variables.)

Comment: `?- has3Parent(A), A = non_person.` succeeds incorrectly.  Also, redundant facts will influence `has3Parent/1`. Think of `parent(ch,p). parent(ch,p). parent(ch,p).` which makes `has3Parent(ch)` succeed.

Answer (score 1):

First a minor remark: You are using a relation `parent/2` with arguments like `parent(Child, Parent)`. There are many who use this name with exchanged arguments, thus `parent(Parent, Child)`. For this reason it is much safer to clarify which order you want directly in the name. Thus `child_parent(Child, Parent)` is a better name, or for short `child_of(Child, Parent)`.

Whenever you are attempting to define a predicate, first consider how this predicate will behave when definitions it depends upon change.  In your case, what happens if further facts are added to `child_of/2`?

You originally asked for having **at least** 3 parents, let's call this relation `has3parentsminimum/1`. Then a definition with exactly 3 parents `has3parents/1` and then @Amadan's [definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55644849/772868) `has3parentsA/1`.

Lets compare the set of solutions before and after adding facts to `child_of/2`.

`has3parentsminimum/1`: the set of solutions increases or stays the same.  It increases should a further child now have 3 or more parents.

`has3parents/1`: the set of solutions may increase or decrease or both (thus just change). Since some children may now have four or more  parents and others have now three.

`has3parentsA/1`: like `has3parents/1` but additionally, the set of solutions may also change if a redundant fact is added.

So `has3parentsminimum/1` is quite stable when adding further facts. This is known as **monotonicity**: When adding new clauses, everything you knew was true before stays true. Staying in the monotonic subset of Prolog as long as possible is a very good idea, since it is in this part where you can learn a lot about relations.  (And that is probably the reason why you got this exercise.)

The most natural definition for `has3parentsminimum/1` is to use `dif/2`:

```
has3parentsminimum(Ch) :-
   dif(P1,P2), dif(P1,P3), dif(P2, P3),  % all parents are different
   child_of(Ch, P1),
   child_of(Ch, P2),
   child_of(Ch, P3).
```

That's probably as far as you need to go. Yes, you will get 3! = 6 redundant solutions for each child with exactly three parents, and even more so for children with more than 3 parents, but the set of solutions is fine.

But there are further improvements possible (that come at a certain price). Provided that `child_of/2` contains ground facts only, you can write:

```
has3parentsminimum(Ch) :-
   setof(P, child_of(Ch, P), [_,_,_|_]).
```